# When do today's OHLC prices reflect in googlefinance function in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, stocks, google-finance

It's 9.30 PM while the market closed at 3.30 PM. Still googlefinance() functions are unable to fetch today's OHLC prices. Yesterday's prices are available though.
When do they (today's prices) reflect?

Answer (score 1):

currently there is some issue with googlefinance, it is showing #NA for some scripts. Check this bug at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76403135